# How to change value of a private variable in a JavaScript method from outside?

Tags: javascript, object

I have object `o`.  How can I change the value of variable `v` from 123 to 321 without overriding the entire method `m`?

```
var o={
    p:123,
    m: function(a){
        var v=123;
        alert(v);
    }
};
```

Comment: With the code as-is, you can't.

Comment: Are we allowed to change the initial definition of `m` in this game? Or does it have to stay the way you have it above?

Comment: @JLRishe.  If need be.  Ideally, I didn't want to have to, but was thinking the same thing.

Comment: @user1032531 Ok, even so, it's extremely unclear what you want to do or why. What is the purpose of this? It's not possible to directly interact with variables that are defined inside a function.

Comment: @JLRishe  I have a jQuery plugin which requires a great big object.  I created the object in one file, and use it on multiple pages.  I now have a need where I just need to tweak one part (i.e. 123 to 321).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the object to be like this:

```
var o = {
    p: 123,
    v: 123,
    m: function(a) {
        var v = this.v;
        alert(v);
    }
};
```

Then if you need to change `v` on a case-by-case basis, just do:

```
o.v = 321;
```

Comment: Thanks.  I was thinking I might have to do something like this, but hoping for some magic solution.  This will work fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are simply wanting to override the value, then using a variable, instead of a hardcoded value in the object would do the trick:

```
var x = 321;

var o = {
    p: 123,
    m: function(a) {
        var v = x;
        alert(v);
    }
};
```

At that point, when you call `o.m(1);`, you get an alert with the value "321" in it. If you then change the value of `x` to "456", `o.m(1);` will return that value the next time.